# How to get @property methods in asdict?

Tags: python, python-attrs

I have something like:

```
from attr import attrs, attrib

@attrs
class Foo():
    max_count = attrib()
    @property
    def get_max_plus_one(self):
         return self.max_count + 1
```

Now when I do:

```
f = Foo(max_count=2)
f.get_max_plus_one =>3
```

I want to convert this to dict:

```
{'max_count':2, 'get_max_plus_one': 3}
```

When I used `attr.asdict(f)` I do not get the `@property`. I get only
`{'max_count':2}`.

What is the cleanest way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, you can use `dir` on the object, and get only the properties that do not start with `__` i.e. ignore the magic methods:

```
In [496]: class Foo():
     ...:     def __init__(self):
     ...:         self.max_count = 2
     ...:     @property
     ...:     def get_max_plus_one(self):
     ...:          return self.max_count + 1
     ...:     

In [497]: f = Foo()

In [498]: {prop: getattr(f, prop) for prop in dir(f) if not prop.startswith('__')}
Out[498]: {'get_max_plus_one': 3, 'max_count': 2}
```

---

To handle the regular methods that do not start with `__`, you can add a `callable` test:

```
In [521]: class Foo():
     ...:     def __init__(self):
     ...:         self.max_count = 2
     ...:     @property
     ...:     def get_max_plus_one(self):
     ...:          return self.max_count + 1
     ...:     def spam(self):
     ...:         return 10
     ...:     

In [522]: f = Foo()

In [523]: {prop: getattr(f, prop) for prop in dir(f) if not (prop.startswith('__') or callable(getattr(Foo, prop, None)))}
Out[523]: {'get_max_plus_one': 3, 'max_count': 2}
```

Comment: What about all the methods in `Foo`, and all the methods in the MRO of `Foo`? But `getattr` here was definitely more appropriate.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That gets tricky very quickly, i liked your generic approach but my solution is sort of specific.

Comment: Well, my point was simply that if `Foo` has any methods, like `Foo.doStuff` you'll end up with a bunch of bound methods.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Fair enough. Edited.

Comment: Both snippets produce the same result — so what's the point of adding the `callable` test?

Answer (score 3):

In general, you would have to iterate over the *classes* attributes and check for instances of `property` and then call the properties `__get__` method using the instance. So, something like:

```
In [16]: class A:
    ...:     @property
    ...:     def x(self):
    ...:         return 42
    ...:     @property
    ...:     def y(self):
    ...:         return 'foo'
    ...:

In [17]: a = A()

In [18]: vars(a)
Out[18]: {}

In [19]: a.x
Out[19]: 42

In [20]: a.y
Out[20]: 'foo'

In [21]: {n:p.__get__(a) for n, p in vars(A).items() if isinstance(p, property)}
Out[21]: {'x': 42, 'y': 'foo'}
```

Answer (score 3):

I’m afraid that isn’t supported by `attrs` at the moment. You may want to follow/comment on https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/353 which may give you what you want eventually.

Answer (score 0):

If you define:

```py
import attr

def attr2dict(inst):
    dic = attr.asdict(inst)
    dic.update({n: p.__get__(inst) for n, p in vars(type(inst)).items() if isinstance(p, property)})
    return dic
```

Then you get what you were looking for:

```py
>>> attr2dict(f)
{'max_count': 2, 'get_max_plus_one': 3}
```